# Querying ArcSDE feature class attribute table after joining

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, vba, attribute-joins

I am trying to query an ArcSDE Feature Class after joining using Iqueryfilter

I have two SDE feature classes:

1. Subdivisions :       which  has details of subdivision and districts (parent)
2. Districts:    Which has details of districts and States (parent)

I want to find out what are the subdivisions in a state. For this I joined Districts table to Subdivision table and  now I can do attribute query in ArcMap and get the divisions in a state using select by attribute tool (example :  `Districts.statename =  'A'`  selects all the divisions in the state ‘A’)

Now I want to do the same using VBA -   I am using the  following method but it gives me  ORA-00904 error :  “Districts”.”statename” : invalid identifier.

How do I get this done?

```
Dim pQFilter As IQueryFilter

Set pQFilter = New QueryFilter

Dim pFeature As IFeature

pQFilter.WhereClause =  " Districts.statename = 'A'"   
  
Dim myFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer

Set myFeatureLayer =   “Districts”

Dim pFCursor As IFeatureCursor

Set pFCursor = myFeatureLayer.Search(pQFilter, False)

Set pFeature = pFCursor.NextFeature()
```

Comment: Raj, Try your where clause without Districts.statename enclosed within the double quotes.

Comment: Thanks artwork21,but it is not working.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because had not been answered in  9 years